# A conjecture (or theorem?) on unit vectors in a Euclidean space

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, convexity

I have heard (if I am not mistaken) that there exists the following conjecture (or theorem?).

Let $u_1,\dots,u_n$ be unit vectors in an $n$-dimensional Euclidean vector space. Then there exists another unit vector $x$ such that 
$$(\prod_{i=1}^n |(x,u_i)|)^{1/n}\geq 1/\sqrt{n}.$$

> Is it conjecture or theorem? In either case I would be interested to have a reference.

Remark. This post is a continuation of the previous one: [Reference to a conjecture on unit vectors in Euclidean space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352720/reference-to-a-conjecture-on-unit-vectors-in-euclidean-space)

Comment: Yep, this one (to the best of my knowledge) is still open for large $n$ (small $n$ are fine, say, for $n\le 5$, the same idea as I used for the sum works and you can modify it slightly to go up a little bit. It also works for a small perturbation of an orthonormal system, so the counterexample, if it exists, should be rather skewed). Unfortunately, I'm not good with references, so I'll leave that part to someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer. I tried the log sum inequality applied to the log of the left hand side, but no luck.

Assume the unit vectors $u_i$ are orthogonal and use a change of basis so that $u_i=e_i,$ the vector with the sole nozero entry equal to one in the $i^{th}$ component.

Taking $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\pm 1,\pm 1,\ldots,\pm 1),$$
achieves your lower bound and perturbing $x$ only increases the LHS of your inequality.

Now consider the $u_i$ below with only two vectors changed and $\theta \in (0,1)$:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
(& \sqrt{1-\theta^2} & \theta & 0 & \cdots & 0& ),\\
(& \theta &\sqrt{1-\theta^2} & 0 & \cdots & 0& ),\\
(& \sqrt{1-\theta^2} & \theta & 0 & \cdots & 0& ),\\
&&& \ddots &&&\\
(&0 & 0& 0 &\cdots & 1&)\\
\end{array}
$$
and note that once again the left hand side of the inequality increases.

I feel that arguments along this line may prove the inequality.

Comment: this was too long to enter as a comment. I'd be interested to see if the downvoter has something constructive to contribute to the question or my comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm confused why you're bringing up whether the downvote can contribute to the *question*. If they have a reason to downvote your answer, that is enough; they don't need to be able to contribute to the question

Comment: For orthogonal vectors the inequality is satisfied by $ x = \frac{y}{||y||}$, with $y = \sum_i u_i$.